# Insert newline (\n) in UITextfield by clicking the Return key

Tags: xcode

I'm looking for this answer for quite some time before posting the question here. I'm quite sure it should be easy but....

I have a UITextField and when a user taps the Return Key a newline should be inserted. Just like WhatsApp is doing with the return key.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UITextField does not support multiple lines. You should go with UITextField, as Yaman has mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` have this kind of behaviour. Try to use it instead of a `UITextField`

Comment: That was it, I knew it was simple. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!